# How to upgrade to autoconf 2.69 with MinGW / MSYS

Tags: mingw, autoconf, msys

Struggling with configure because it require at least autoconf 2.69 or higher, whereas 2.68 is installed..
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved my issue. 
Turns out that building / installing autoconf 2.69 from source works :

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
tar xvfvz autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
cd autoconf-2.69
./configure
make
make install
```